# How long does the `httpx.AsyncClient` can "live" without closing the event loop?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, python-asyncio, httpx

I have an endpoint in `Django` that orchestrates a bunch of API calls to other underlying services. I intend to use a long-lived instance of `httpx.AsyncClient` - which will be ultimately responsible for the API calls.

```py
from functools import partial


class Api:  # for historical reasons, this class has both sync and async methods
   ...


AsyncApi = partial(Api, async_client=httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=30))


class MyViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
   @action(...)
   def merge(self, request: Request) -> Response:
      ...
      result = async_to_sync(merge_task)(..., api=AsyncApi(token=request.auth))
      ...
```

I'm doing some tests in a dummy server and I can see that sometimes `merge_task` captures `RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')` when calling `api` (or, ultimately, the long-lived instance of `httpx.AsyncClient`) so I'd bet that the loop for `httpx.AsyncClient` is closed after some time and there's no issue with `asgiref`'s `async_to_sync`.

Am I correct? If so, the only solution is to instantiate `httpx.AsyncClient` on every request?

I tried do call `merge_task` using the endpoint but it captured `RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')`. The expectation is to not raise any error related to async programming

Comment: I'd say that using an `AsyncClient` is the way to go for frequent requests to the same server. Nevertheless, it seems in your case that these are not so frequent, thus making it useless to keep the connection open. It should be further investigated. That being said, I guess that your server does not keep the connection alive and closes the loop. I would investigate that aspect and check the settings of `httpx`

Comment: Maybe adjusting or disabling the `timeout` completely may help https://www.python-httpx.org/quickstart/#timeouts